# SignalR communication between Asp.net MVC .Net 6 and View cshtml via javascript in single application

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to send message just from server to client(one way) in single MVC application via SignalR. Javascript is connected to Hub but don't get new messages.

[image]

**Server Side:**

**Send new message to all clients**

```
IHubContext<SignalUpdateHub> hubContext = new IHubContext<SignalUpdateHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendAsync","newMessge")
```

- **Startup:**

  ```
   ConfigureService(){
       services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
       {
            builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
       }));
       services.AddSignalR(o=> o.EnableDetailedErrors = true);
   }

   Configure(){
      app.UseCors("corsapp");

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
         endpoints.MapHub<SignalUpdateHub>("/signalUpdate");

      });
   }
  ```
- **Hub:**

  ```
    public class SignalUpdateHub : Hub
   {
      public void SendAsync(string message)
      {
         Clients.All.SendAsync("sendNewSignal",message);
      }
   }
  ```

**Client Side javascript:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
   var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("https://localhost:2041/signalUpdate")
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
    .build();

   connection.on("sendNewSignal", function(message)=> {
      console.log(message)
   });

   function start() {
      try {
        connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(start, 5000);
      }
  };

  connection.onclose(async () => {
     start();
  });
  start();
})
```

I get SignalR Connected in console but don't get new signal

Comment: There's no offline capabilities in SignalR. I don't know when you're calling SendAsync in the hub, but if it's not in the connect async method then something else will have to trigger it when you login.

Comment: Change `hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendAsync","newMessge")` to "sendNewSignal"

Comment: Did not work @Brennan